# Which countries has the US publicly threatened to sanction if they expel US troops, say, in the past 25 years?

Tags: united-states, military, sanctions, foreign-policy, rhetoric

Back [in 2020](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/01/06/middleeast/iraq-us-troops-explainer-intl/index.html),

> When Iraq’s parliament voted to expel American troops from the country Sunday, it was an apparent bid by the government to extract the country from an escalating US-Iran proxy war. [...]
>
> In response, Trump has threatened to sanction Baghdad “like they’ve never seen before ever,” if Iraq were to expel US troops. “It’ll make Iranian sanctions look somewhat tame,” he added [...]

One can imagine that such threats might have been uttered, more or less explicitly, on other occasions. But were they so publicly, say in the past 25 years? And if there's nothing that explicit about imposing sanctions, was at least e.g. suggested that US aid would be cut/adjusted?

Comment: It's not a political question in itself. There is nothing to discuss, you just need to look for documentation. This website is not meant to ask people to make google searches for you.